# Div overflows to next line when it should not

Tags: html, css

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/mbowen/pen/YypeLP)

This is the parent container:

```
.fixed-width{
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I want to increase the left and right padding between the top navigation list items but it keeps overflowing some of the items to the next line.

How do I keep it from putting those items on a new line and instead just overflow out of its boundaries without changing the width of the parent container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the CSS `overflow` property and set it to hidden:

```
.fixed-width {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Already tried that, doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wan't them to be bound then you could apply a z-index on the property allowing it to sit on top of the lower stack, and would therefore not wrap onto a new line regardless of the width of its parent.

```
<div class='container'>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="box"></li> 
        <li class="box"></li>
        <li class="box"></li>     
    </ul>
</div>



.nav{
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
.box{
    float:left;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    margin:0 10px;
    list-style-type:none;
    background-color:red;
}
.container{
    width:100px;
    height:70px;
    background-color:black;
}
```

here's and example [z-index-example](https://jsfiddle.net/a93racxf/)